# How to set values using JSP Expression Language without JSTL <c:set> tag?

Tags: jsp, el

I could get a value using `${session.name}`. Is there any way to set a value in JSP using Expression Language? I am not asking about using `<c:set>` tag.

```
${param.name}
${session.name}
${request.hhh}
```

We get values in this way, can we set these value using the same way?

Please suggest with examples.

Comment: `<c:set>` **is** how to do it. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: i am just learning jsp. I have read in a text as we can use EL to set and get values and they showed the above examples to get, and i tried, working well. But I want to know how this to use set value. Is there no way other than c:set. If so just say it..

Answer (score 3):

EL syntax is very minimal on purpose, and it is designed to display and format data rather than change it. The reason for this is to encourage an MVC approach, where business logic has already been processed before anything is displayed. It also has the benefit of being very easy to learn, even for non-programmers.

`<c:set>` is the way to do it. EL doesn't have an equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible since EL 3.0 (introduced in Java EE 7 at May 2013) using `=` operator.

```
${param.name = "123"}
${session.name = "abc"}
${request.hhh = "xyz"}
```

Comment: What he wants is to use the same old (and dinossaur) way getter ${param.name} to set param value. My answer show how ${param.name="123"}, but it has a drawback: characters will be shown because ${} will evaluate what is inside and return it.

Answer (score 1):

```
${myVariable = "666" ; ""}
```

From the [EL 3.0 spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/el-3_0-fr-spec/EL3.0.FR.pdf) section 1.14:

> **Semicolon Operator - `A ; B`**
>
> The semicolon operator behaves like the comma operator in C.
> To evaluate `A;B`, `A` is first evaluated, and its value is discarded.
> `B` is then evaluated and its value is returned.

So we evaluate an assignment, discard that result and evaluate and return an empty String.

Answer (score 0):

Standard JSP/JSTL features support 3 ways to set value to bean property or Map.

1. c:set ( for both java bean and java map )
2. jsp:setProperty ( only for java bean properties. Not MAP )
3. jsp scriptless ( write java code in jsp )

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781782176466/1/ch01lvl1sec14/el-3-0-overview) : EL 3.0 (JSR 341, part of Java EE 7) represents a major boost of EL 2.2. The main features of EL 3.0 are as follows:

> ```
> New operators +, =, and ;
>
> Lambda expressions
>
> Collection objects support
>
> An API for standalone environments
> ```

Working with the assignment operator

In an expression of type, x = y, the assignment operator (=), assign the value of y to x. In order to avoid an error of the kind PropertyNotWritableException, the x value must be an lvalue. The following examples show you how to use this operator in two simple expressions:

```
#{x = 3} evaluates to 3

#{y = x + 5} evaluates to 8
```

The assignment operator is right-associative (z = y = x is equivalent with z = (y = x)). For example, #{z = y = x + 4} evaluates to 7.